# Can I use non-static variables when initializing static variables in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, class, variables, static

Can I use non-static variables during initialization of static variables in a JavaScript class?
If it's possible, then in which cases can I use it?
In my test code, it doesn't work like I expected:

```
class Test1 {
  static commonParam = [
    ['Test1', ['Test1', 'Test2', this.param1]]
  ];
  constructor(param1) {
    this.param1=param1;
    console.log(`Test1 param1: ${this.param1}`);
  };
  pintCommonparam(){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(Test1.commonParam));
  }
}

t1 = new Test1(1);
t1.pintCommonparam();
```

code execution result:

```
> "Test1 param1: 1"
> "[["Test1",["Test1","Test2",null]]]"
```

I expected that instead of null the last value of the array would be equal to the value of this.param1

Answer (score -1):

Static variables are initialized when you create your class, while constructor runs after using `new Test1(1)`. It means that `commonParam` takes the value before you run class constructor and `this.param1` is  actually null.

You can try to redefine static variable in constructor like:

```
constructor(param1) {
    this.param1=param1;
    Test1.commonParam = [
      ['Test1', ['Test1', 'Test2', param1]]
    ];
    console.log(`Test1 param1: ${this.param1}`);
};
```

**Remember** that every single object will modify this static variable.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use non-static variables during initialisation of static variables.

In fact it is impossible. I think you need to understand the difference between Class definition and Class instantiation.

The class definition is created before you instantiate an object with the new reserve word. Then 'this' in the static method refers to the class rather than object.

You could change a static variable by calling a non static-method:

```js
class Test1 {
  static commonParam = [
    ['Test1', ['Test1', 'Test2', 'ToBeChanged']]
  ];
  constructor(param1) {
    this.param1=param1;
    console.log(`Test1 param1: ${this.param1}`);
  };

  updateStatic()
  {
    Test1.commonParam[0][1][2] = this.param1
  }

  pintCommonparam(){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(Test1.commonParam));
  }
}

t1 = new Test1('it Should change!!!');
t1.updateStatic()
t1.pintCommonparam();
```

Comment: @backloz are you able to check the right answer so other people can take advantage of the problem and the resolution?